# PHP looping problem?

Tags: php

I have this script that displays a max of 5 images for each row, but for some reason my `<ul>` tag won't close correctly if the number of items isn't an exact multiple of 5. How can I correct this problem so the `<ul>` tag will close even if the number of listed images is less then 5?

Here is my PHP code.

```
if (!$dbc) {
    print mysqli_error($mysqli);
} else {
    $row_count = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){ 
        if($row_count % 5 == 0){
         echo "<ul>";
        }
       echo "<li><a href='" .$row["url"]. "' title='".$row['title']."'>";
        echo "<img src='".$row['src']."'></a></li>";
       if($row_count % 5 == 4) {
         echo "</ul>";
       }
       $row_count++;
    }

}
```

Comment: *(tipp)* [`printf`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) can make your code a lot more readable

Comment: Or alternatively, do this: `echo "<li><a href='{$row['url']}'</a></li>";`

Comment: @Gordon how will print_f help me with this problem?

Comment: nope, the printf is just kind of equivalent for echo, while your problem is about logics.

Comment: @sIK It's just a general tipp to improve your code legibility; a sidenote. It wasn't meant to help with your actual problem.

Comment: @Gordon I figured that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Another note: I think it is perfectly legal to use a table instead of lists ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$multiple = false;

if (!$dbc) {
    print mysqli_error($mysqli);
} else {
    $row_count = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){ 
        if($row_count % 5 == 0){
         echo "<ul>";
        }
       echo "<li><a href='" .$row["url"]. "' title='".$row['title']."'>";
        echo "<img src='".$row['src']."'></a></li>";
       if($row_count % 5 == 4) {
         $multiple = true;
         echo "</ul>";
       } else {
        $multiple = false;
       }
       $row_count++;
    }
    if($multiple == false) {
        echo "</ul>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

below the loop, check if

```
if (!$dbc) {
    print mysqli_error($mysqli);
} else {
    $row_count = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){ 
        if($row_count % 5 == 0){
         echo "<ul>";
        }
       echo "<li><a href='" .$row["url"]. "' title='".$row['title']."'>";
        echo "<img src='".$row['src']."'></a></li>";
       if($row_count % 5 == 4) {
         echo "</ul>";
       }
       $row_count++;
    }
    if ( (($row_count % 5) > 0) && (($row_count % 5) < 4))
        echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: exactly where below the loop?

Comment: below the closing "}" of "while", but of course inside "else" statement code.
I've edited the answer to show you where exactly ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$dbc) {
print mysqli_error($mysqli);} else {
$row_count = 0;
//tank start
$total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($dbc);
//tank end
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){ 
    if($row_count % 5 == 0){
     echo "<ul>";
    }
   echo "<li><a href='" .$row["url"]. "' title='".$row['title']."'>";
    echo "<img src='".$row['src']."'></a></li>";
   //tank start
   if($row_count % 5 == 4 || $row_count==$total_rows) {
   //tank end
     echo "</ul>";
   }
   $row_count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my updated solution. I think it looks a little clearer. I do setup a few variables to get rid of some IF statements, and replace them with FOR loops. Mainly for readability and it's the way i thought of doing it.

```
$itemsperrow = 5;
$items = mysqli_num_rows($dbc);
$rows = $items / $itemsperrow;
$itemcount = 0;

if (!$dbc)
{
    echo(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
else
{
    for ($int = 0; $int < $rows; $int++)
    {
        echo "<ul>";

        for ($item = 0; $item < $itemsperrow; $item++)
        {
            if ($itemcount >= $items)
            {
                echo "</ul>";
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc);
                echo "<li><a href='". $row["url"] . "'>";
                echo "<img src='" . $row["src"] . "' title='" . $row["title"] . "'/></a></li>";
                $itemcount++;
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";        
    }
}
```